# VS 2010 C++ unable to load references due to out of date version number

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, reference, version

When I set references for a C++ project in Visual Studio 2010, it fails to load a reference dll from another c# project because of a version mismatch. Building a C# project that references another c# project is no issue for me. I tried hard coding the version number for the c# project which worked great, but that was simply for testing and not a permanent solution.

Is there a way to automatically update the reference version number within the c++ project so that when I build these projects together I don't run into this issue?

Comment: How do you reference your C# DLL in C++?